# How can I add an animation to my text balloon? It's a Twitch Alert (bits alert as example)

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to create my own Twitch Alert in Streamlabs with code.

How can I add an animation to my text balloon? I haven't found videos or instructions on how to do this, so I need some assistance.

CSS

```css
#alert-user-message{
  min-width: 48px;
  min-height: 32px;
  max-width: 605px;
  max-height: 158px;
  margin-bottom: -195px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding: 16px;
  background: #FFF; border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px; border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(9, 19, 20, 0.35);
  position: relative;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#alert-user-message:before{
  content:"\A";
  left: calc(50% - 2rem);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0rem 2rem 2rem 2rem;
  border-color: transparent transparent #FFF transparent; 
  position: fixed !important;
  margin-top: -35px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

HTML

```html
<!-- alert image -->
<div id="alert-image-wrap">
  <div id="alert-image"></div>
</div>

<!-- main alert box window -->
<div id="alert-text-wrap">

  <!-- alert text -->
  <div id="alert-text">

    <!-- alert message -->
    <!-- messageTemplate will be replaced with your message template -->
    <!-- for example : {name} is now following! or {name} donated {amount} -->

    <div id="alert-message">}</div>
    <div id="alert-user-message"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What animation are you wanting to add?

Answer (score 0):

This [guide](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) should help you, it shows how it's easy to make CSS animations for buttons or text and it's quite a trusted website that I've used quite a few times while learning HTML, CSS and Javascript.